# Which constructor is getting called for below string code?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, list-initialization, stdinitializerlist

I was reading c++ primer and came across an example of list initialization for vector where the author mentioned that if list initialization isn't possible, the compiler then looks for other ways to initialize the object. Below is such an example for vector of string.

```
vector<string> v8{10, "hi"};
```

This creates a vector of 10 elements with value "hi". This I think is because list initialization falls back on below constructor to create the vector.

```
vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

I tried similar kind of list initialization for String

```
std::string s1{10, 'c'};
```

I was expecting it to create a string "cccccccccc" because there is a constructor available for it

```
basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

But it prints only "c"? Which string constructor is getting used here?

Comment: It actually prints `"\nc"`. Noticed something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's coming into play here are the rules for [`direct-list-initialization`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which has one of the syntax as

```
T object { arg1, arg2, ... };
```

Here, in the case of `std::string s{10, 'c'}`, `T` in the above syntax is `std::string` and the rule that applies is

> Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases: All
> constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument, or
> as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values,
> are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single
> argument of type std::initializer_list

Since there is a constructor of `std::string` that takes in an initializer list with the other arguments as default, namely [constructor (9)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

```
basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> ilist,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

that participates in this resolution since `10` can be implicitly converted to `char` and what you get is a `std::initializer_list<char>` of `{'\n', 'c'}` of 2 characters.

---

In the case of `std::vector<std::string> v{10. "hi"}`, `T` is `std::vector<std::string>` in the syntax for `direct-list-initialization` as mentioned above.

Now, since `10` can't be implicitly converted to `std::string`, no such `std::initializer_list<std::string>` can be constructed and thus the next alternative for `direct-list-initialization` is

> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T
> participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that
> consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction
> that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed.

This produces a match with [constructor 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

```
explicit vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

since neither of the conversions is non-narrowing.

---

Now coming to what you wanted to achieve with `std::string s{10, 'c'}`, that should be done using `std::string s(10, c)` where there is no `list-initialization` involved.

```
std::string s1{10, 'c'}, s2(10, 'c');
std::cout<<'['<<s1<<']'<<'['<<s2<<']'<<'\n';
```

Output:

```
[
c][cccccccccc]
```

Note that printing `s1` produces a new line before the `c` since it's actually `['\n', 'c']`, whereas `s2` is exactly what you'd expect i.e. 10 `c` characters.

Answer (score 3):

The [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) taking `std::initiazer_list` gets called.

```
constexpr basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> ilist,
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

`10` is an `int`, which could convert to `char` implicitly, and `std::initializer_list<char>` could be constructed from `{10, 'c'}` as containing two `char`s, the 1st one with ASCII value `10`, the 2nd one as `c`.

On the other hand for `std::vector<std::string>`, `{10, "hi"}` can't be used to construct `std::initializer_list<std::string>` since `10` can't be converted to `std::string`, then the constructor taking `std::initializer_list<std::string>` won't be used.